# how to make everything appear bigger for my responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to do a responsive design and through searching online I can't get what I am looking for but I want everything to appear bigger on my website pages. Instead of doing each element for example `font-size:1.4em;`, how would I do for all the pages ?

Comment: If you used em's or other relative pixel sizes through out, you can simply enlarge body or your outermost wrapper div font and the rest will inherit accordingly.

Comment: If you had used `rem` unit everywhere, you could simply achieve that by altering the `font-size` of the root element.

Comment: @briansol I've used mostly px, but that sounds like a good idea

Comment: Try body{ font-size: 130%; }  Play with the percents until you get what you want. Add this in the media queries :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just add this in the header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

From the comments I think that you don't have a proper viewport setup and that is why everything looks smaller on mobile devices :)

Comment: I already have this..thanks...my firefox can read it but safari and Iphone cant read it

Comment: This is tested on iPhone and other Mac devices and it works 100%. So something else is wrong :) If you make a fiddle you will get more help for your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using two new CSS3 units for that, called vw and vh. Here's and introductory article: http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

For example (from the article):

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: thanks for help, but I want to have it done everywhere not just font-size

Comment: These units can be used on anything, including width and height properties.